# Equal height content within columns bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, height

I know, I know,
bootstrap 4 comes pre-loaded with equal height columns. Why then is the height of each individual p tag within each column dictated by the length of the string of text and not by the column height? I just want each client bubble to appear uniform with the rest on the list, any help would be amazing. Screenshots of the site and relevant code snippets are included.

[list of clients with unequal heights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpoGv.png)

```css
.clients {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.cli {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: .9em;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, .6);
  padding: 38px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #848888;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="clients">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4">
      <p class="cli m-4">Towson University Art Education Department</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4">
      <p class="cli m-4">Baltimore City Public Schools’ New Teacher Summer Institute</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4">
      <p class="cli m-4">Johns Hopkins University School of Education</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4 ">
      <p class="cli m-4">SOURCE at Johns Hopkins University</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4">
      <p class="cli m-4">The Federal Judiciary Center</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4">
      <p class="cli m-4">Waverly Elementary/Middle School</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4">
      <p class="cli m-4">Baltimore Southwest Partnership</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4">
      <p class="cli m-4">The Gallery Church Baltimore</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4">
      <p class="cli m-4">Urban Teachers Baltimore</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4">
      <p class="cli m-4">Baltimore Curriculum Project</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4">
      <p class="cli m-4">Baltimore Collegetown Network</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4">
      <p class="cli m-4">The Foundry Church Baltimore</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
      <p class="cli m-4">Clemson University Fellowship of Christian Athletes</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
      <p class="cli m-4">Johns Hopkins Hospital Lifeline Critical Care Transport Team</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the `.cli ` elements within a row to be equal height? Or _all_ of the  `.cli` elements equal height?

Comment: have you tried using flex-box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is adding flexbox to the `.col` elements. And then tell your `.cli` to grow using flex:

```
.col-sm-12 {
  display: flex;
}
```

and

```
.cli {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Working example:
https://codepen.io/sergiofruto/pen/KKzebEY

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much! This works perfectly. I am learning bootstrap as I go to make this website and will definitely read more about how flexbox works after this. Thanks again.